# Java time in GMT

Tags: java, grails, date, gmt

I have a Grails application with the following code:

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime() //Also tried new Date()
println "now: " + now
```

When I do this, I get `now: Thu Aug 18 12:47:09 CDT 2011`. I need the date to be in GMT, not local time because I need to store the GMT time in a database. I can use a simpleDateFormat object to print out the time in GMT, but I need to actually store it as GMT.

**Question:** How do I convert a Date object to a Date object using GMT?

Comment: @jpredham should probably get the "answer" to this question as he is correct on retrieving the date/time as GMT. (I tested it myself and found it true.) Plus he's newer and the rest of us already have quite a bit of reputation.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This accentuates why Java sucks at time. The previous posts are all close, but we need to be very careful about getting the current time in GMT, and getting the current time in CDT and *calling* it GMT.

```
TimeZone reference = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
Calendar myCal = Calendar.getInstance(reference);
```

This is the current time in GMT, with a timezone context of GMT.

To convert to a Date object which keeps the zone intact you'll need to call:

```
TimeZone.setDefault(reference);
```

This setting will last as long as your current JVM. Now calling get Time should produce the desired result.

```
myCal.getTime();
```

Comment: Kudos to you! I altered my post to better reflect you what said. And even the ZONE_OFFSET thing didn't work. Good catch!

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you really want time in GMT, you need to get it as GMT (@jpredham is right. Kudos to you! Editing my post to reflect this)

So do the following

```
//this option uses TimeZone
TimeZone gmtTimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT");
TimeZone.setDefault(gmtTimeZone);
Calendar calendar = Calender.getInstance(gmtTimeZone);

Date myDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
println Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT')).format('HH:mm:ss')
```

Note that when you convert to a date, you lose the timezone information.  When Java/Groovy formats your Date for printing, it automatically formats it for your local timezone.  Don't worry, your date doesn't have a timezone associated with it.  You can add the proper timezone back in when you display it like so:

```
Date now = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT')).time
def formatter = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat('HH:mm:ss')
formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone('GMT')
println formatter.format(now)
```

Answer (score 0):

Internally a Calendar object stores the time in UTC (the modern name for GMT).  `getTimeInMillis()` returns a UTC value, and is probably what you want to store.

Answer (score 0):

You should try GregorianCalendar#setTimeZone(TimeZone timeZone).

Answer (score 0):

Using System.currentTimeMillis() is not only much faster than using Calendar or Date, it always gives you the GMT time. If you want to display this time, you can use SimpleDateFormat, setting the time zone to what ever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing  date-time object with its string representation. All common date-time libraries in Java (java.util.Date, Joda-Time, java.time in Java 8) internally track a fractional number of seconds since the first moment of 1970 in UTC while ignoring leap seconds. So in all three libraries, the date-time is *internally* always in UTC/GMT.

So your question of how to convert a Date object to a Date object in GMT (UTC) makes no sense.

The two better libraries (Joda-Time and java.time) also track a time zone inside the date-time object. The notoriously troublesome java.util.Date has no time zone assigned yet confusingly applies the JVM's current default time zone when it's `toString` method is invoked.

For the record, Joda-Time makes short work of this.

```
DateTime nowUtc = DateTime.now( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Calling that object's toString method generates a string in ISO 8601 format in Zulu (UTC) time.

Search StackOverflow for "Joda" and "formatter" to find many examples of adjusting to other time zones.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now()    // Capture current moment in UTC.
    .toString()  // Generate a String object in standard ISO 8601 format, YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSSSSSSSSZ.
```

> 2018-02-16T23:28:01.101324Z

## java.time

The modern approach uses *java.time* classes. Avoid the troublesome legacy date-time classes entirely.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format by calling `toString`.

```
String output = instant.toString() ;
```

If you need more flexibility than `Instant` provides, such as formatting while generating strings, use `OffsetDateTime` with the constant `ZoneOffset.UTC`.

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.now( ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;  // Capture the current moment in UTC.
```

To generate strings in non-standard formats, use a `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings nor java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).