# How to Pass Array of Timestamps to Postgres Function using Java/JDBC?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, postgresql-9.1

How do I pass an array of timestamps to the Postgres function using Java and JDBC?

Here's the signature of the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getlistcount(_id integer, _subs text, _download_array timestamp without time zone[], _filter integer, _fault text) RETURNS refcursor AS...
```

Here is the Java code that creates the array:

```
GregorianCalendar[] dataDownloads = 
        downloadTimes.toArray(new GregorianCalendar[downloadTimes.size()]);

Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("timestamp", dataDownloads);
cstmt.setArray(4, sqlArray);
```

The downloadTimes are List passed into the Java function.

One hint: we need to concatenate the time with the date, according to the [Postgres documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/datatype-datetime.html).

Comment: I see that you're using `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE`.  In almost every use case, `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` is better; it represents an actual moment in time, while the other does not.

Comment: @KGrittn, that makes sense. We're getting the timezone from the download-time (see below), save the timezone with the timestamp. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [an answer on StackOverflow that is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7915963/in-jdbc-when-calling-preparedstatement-setarray-how-do-i-specify-the-timezon), but uses the PreparedStatement rather than the JDBC notation.

```
//Get timezone from first entry, assuming all same timezone
if(!downloadTimes.isEmpty()) {
    cal.setTimeZone(downloadTimes.get(0).getTimeZone());
}

//Create an array of timestamps
java.sql.Timestamp [] array = new java.sql.Timestamp [downloadTimes.size()];

for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i] = new java.sql.Timestamp(downloadTimes.get(i).getTimeInMillis());
} 

//pass the array to JDBC call
//conn is the connection, and cstmt is the CallableStatement
Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("timestamp", array);
cstmt.setArray(4, sqlArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

The array doesn't have to be of the old **java.sql.Timestamp** class, you can use java.time classes instead.

Like this

```
LocalDateTime[] localTimes = new LocalDateTime[]{LocalDateTime.now()};
Array sqlArray = conn.createArrayOf("timestamp", localTimes);
cstmt.setArray(4, sqlArray);
```

For *timestamp with zone* use **java.time.OffsetDateTime**

Comment: Thanks for updating with fresher code, @david-lilljegren.  Yes, that's the best-practice for the timestamp with timezone.

Comment: Postgres JDBC driver erases the timezone information, if one passes the type `timestamp` to the `createArrayOf` method. Using the type `timestamptz` will fix this problem.